# Assign rails form-only value to model's another attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have `User` model. One of it's attributes is *phone_number*.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   attr_accessor :phone_number
end
```

In `form_for @user`, I want to have two inputs: `dialing_code` and `number`. Then, when the form is submitted, I want `phone_number` to be equal to these inputs concatenated together. One of the solution would be to make these inputs as `attr_accessor` in the model.

Is there another solution? I was thinking to make these inputs variables only exist in the template, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: If you show the format you plan to use for `dialing_code`, `number`, and `phone_number`, I can help you customize the code below to your needs.

Comment: Since you mentioned, you just want them as template field and not data fields, I think attr_accessors is a pretty good way which solves the problem. Maybe, stick to that :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use an `attr_accessor`, you should use a pattern sometimes referred to as a "virtual attribute." The idea is to make a getter that combines the "real" attributes, and a setter that performs logic and sets the related "real" attributes.

In your case, it might look something like this:

```
def phone_number
  "#{dialing_code}-#{number}"
end

def phone_number=(string)
  return unless string.respond_to?(:split)
  self.dialing_code = string.split('-').first
  self.number = string.split('-')[1..-1].join('-')
end
```

You'll need to tweak this depending on how you want `phone_number` to be displayed and how you want to parse a `phone_number` into its component `dialing_code` and `number`, but the code above gives you the general idea.

Now you can make a new user using a `phone_number` and its `dialing_code` and `number` will be set as expected:

```
>> user = User.new(phone_number: '333-444-5555')
>> user.dialing_code
#> "333"
>> user.number
#> "444-5555"
```

Alternatively, you can set `dialing_code` and `number` individually and still get a `phone_number` as expected:

```
>> user = User.new(dialing_code: '333', number: '444-5555')
>> user.phone_number
#> "333-444-5555"
```

Comment: Would you do it the same if it was not an *accessor*, but rather an attribute saved in database? Then you'd haveto be able to somehow differentiate phone_number as method and phone_number as attribute fetched from DB.

Comment: @abcdef Please clarify: Which attribute or attributes are fields in the database? The answer I provided assumes both `dialing_code` and `number` are database fields, and `phone_number` is not a database field.

Comment: phone_number as database field;
dialing_code and number as only template variables.
I could bind the input directly to phone_numbe, but that's not what the client wants. Long story.

Comment: I think you will have the easiest time if you remove `phone_number` as a field from your database and add `dialing_code` and `number` as fields, and use the code described in this answer. Now your form will match your database, but you can get (or set) `phone_number` directly whenever you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Two(or more) choices: Selection of it depends on how you want to maintain the data and query later.

1. Save `dialing_code`, `number` and `phone_number` as attributes (and data fields).
   In template, ask for dialing_code and number, and construct `phone_number` in a hook.

> ```
> before_save :construct_phone_number
> def construct_phone_number
>   self.phone_number = "#{dialing_code}-#{number}" if dialing_code.present? && number.present?
> end
> ```

2. Retain `dialing_code` and `number` as `attr_accessor` and construct `phone_number`(database field) in the same fashion as above. In this case, `dialing_code` and `number` are sort of throw away attributes. You **can** be okay with it, if you are sure that user input will always be fine and you don't need to debug any sort of issues with `phone_number` later.

Note: You will need to `permit` these virtual attributes in strong parameters.

Comment: There is no reason to have three database fields to do this job. That's duplication of data and will lead to problems. You can use `attr_accessor` for `dialing_code` and `number`.

Comment: To clarify: If you do not need to debug `dialing_code` or `number` and want to treat them as "throw away" attributes, as suggested in this answer, then you should use option #2 of this answer. If you do want to hold onto `dialing_code` and `number` for future debugging or whatever, then you should remove the `phone_number` field and use the virtual attribute method described in my answer. Please don't use the suggestion in #1 of this answer--that road leads to serious problems.